# SQL Parse string to get specific values

Tags: sql

Hi I have this value in a column

```
11-1-11111-349b65eda2-4f8e-413d-b76a-6a2c13d6e494OctWed0800422015-request-response.xml
```

How would I parse this using SQL to get only:

```
11-1-11111-349b65eda2-4f8e-413d-b76a-6a2c13d6e494OctWed0800422015
```

Comment: tell us what is the logic.for parse the string. Remove the text after 8th `-` ? Or maybe remove after length string `> 65`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL-Server  you could use this approach if the right side is always `-request-response.xml`:

```
SELECT FileName,
       Leftpart = LEFT(FileName,CHARINDEX('-request-response.xml',FileName)-1)
FROM MyTable
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92a5b/1/0)</kbd>

This is more fail-safe:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT FileName,
          Length = CHARINDEX('-request-response.xml',FileName) -1
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT LeftPart = CASE WHEN Length < 0 THEN NULL 
                   ELSE LEFT(FileName, Length) END
FROM CTE
```

Comment: If you happen to be using a database that supports `left()` and `charindex()`, which pretty much means SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: i've added that this is for sql-server. Thought that it was but OP didn't mention it.

Comment: I get the error: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @JerryTrac: if the value doesnt contain the search word you'll get a negative length which is not allowed in `LEFT`. That's why i've added the second approach.